# Twilio SMS with links - links being clicked automatically?

Tags: cron, sms, twilio

I have an app that sends SMS's out to a bunch of people. Those messages contain links. They are not using any link shorteners or any other service. They link back to my site. The links themselves are randomized strings, which are stored in my db, which are associated with an action. (Click "yes" or "no" link and the db tracks what you chose.) For ALL users, this works perfectly. With one user - and it's always the same user, as soon as the cron job runs, which triggers this event, his "vote" comes in. This is without him clicking or even seeing the message sometimes.

So, the question: has anyone ever seen or heard of a cell provider or a messaging app or similar that "clicks" links as part of some process before sharing the content with the user? I can't see ANYTHING in the code that would single him out so I'm thinking it has to be something in between when the message goes out and he does what he does. Especially because the timestamp is also always within seconds of the cron job running.

Comment: Have you considered that your cron job might be executing his link?

Answer (score 0):

[Sending an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) can sometimes go through multiple carriers before reaching an end destination. As such, providers may be "handling" the content in this case.

The best thing to do would for any cases of this in the future would be to [write support](https://twilio.com/help/contact) for further investigation.